# Transform SQL to HQL with criteria nvl

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

```
(nvl(SELECT sum(wbs.days * 8 + wbs.hours)
FROM com.vtradex.er.server.model.er.ProjectWbs wbs 
WHERE wbs.project.id=erp.id
AND wbs.user.id= 248 ),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to create stored procedure that will do this query and map it to some property through `@Formula` annotation.